# Difference between ipad/iphone/Universal Application

Tags: objective-c

can you please help me .
what is the Difference between ipad/iphone/Universal Application.

Answer (score 3):

iPad application - Application meant to run on an iPad.

iPhone application - Application meant to run on an iPhone/iPod touch, but can also run on an iPad (in compatibility mode, with the 1x/2x toggle)

Universal Application - Application that runs on both iPad and iPhone/iPod touch and adapts to both screen sizes.

Comment: the names kinda give their uses away, no?

Answer (score 1):

iPad uses different processor type than iPhone or iPod, so universal application carries both binaries.